# MVC6 Facebook identity misses email claim

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core-mvc

I am debugging [MVC6 MusicStore](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/src/MusicStore). What I've found is that Facebook `ExternalIdentity` which is accessed in `ExternalLoginCallback` method does not have an email claim. At the same time my test MVC5 application successfully gets that claim, so it's not the Facebook app problem.

Does anyone know if that is a beta bug?

Comment: Did you try this ? app.UseIdentity()
                .UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                })

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Would you like to move it from comments so I could mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add `email` in the Facebook authentication options in Startup.cs

`app.UseIdentity().UseFacebookAuthentication(options => 
{ 
options.Scope.Add("email"); 
});`

Comment: MVC6 IAppBuilder does not even expose UseIdentity(). Maybe this is a solution for MVC5?

Comment: It actually does expose app.UseIdentity(). Please make sure that you are using package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity'. This is an naswer for MVC6. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this did not work after upgrading to Facebook API v 2.4. However adding .UserInformationEndpoint like this worked:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
    options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location";
});
```